# Cert-Manager k8s, Renewing certificate process

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I have installed cert manager on a k8s cluster:

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace --version v1.5.3 --set installCRDs=true
```

My objective is to do mtls communication between micro-services running in same name-space.

For this purpose I have created a ca issuer .i.e..

```
kubectl get issuer -n sandbox -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
  kind: Issuer
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"cert-manager.io/v1","kind":"Issuer","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"ca-issuer","namespace":"sandbox"},"spec":{"ca":{"secretName":"tls-internal-ca"}}}
    creationTimestamp: "2021-09-16T17:24:58Z"
    generation: 1
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:spec:
          .: {}
          f:ca:
            .: {}
            f:secretName: {}
      manager: HashiCorp
      operation: Update
      time: "2021-09-16T17:24:58Z"
    - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          .: {}
          f:conditions: {}
      manager: controller
      operation: Update
      time: "2021-09-16T17:24:58Z"
    name: ca-issuer
    namespace: sandbox
    resourceVersion: "3895820"
    selfLink: /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/sandbox/issuers/ca-issuer
    uid: 90f0c811-b78d-4346-bb57-68bf607ee468
  spec:
    ca:
      secretName: tls-internal-ca
  status:
    conditions:
      message: Signing CA verified
      observedGeneration: 1
      reason: KeyPairVerified
      status: "True"
      type: Ready
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Using this ca issuer, I have created certificates for my two micro-service .i.e.

```
kubectl get certificate -n sandbox      
NAME                       READY         SECRET             Age
service1-certificate        True    service1-certificate     3d     
service2-certificate        True    service2-certificate     2d23h
```

which is configured as

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: service1
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: sandbox
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-17T10:20:21Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
      f:spec:
        .: {}
        f:commonName: {}
        f:dnsNames: {}
        f:duration: {}
        f:issuerRef:
          .: {}
          f:kind: {}
          f:name: {}
        f:renewBefore: {}
        f:secretName: {}
        f:subject:
          .: {}
          f:organizations: {}
        f:usages: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-09-17T10:20:21Z"
  - apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:privateKey: {}
      f:status:
        .: {}
        f:conditions: {}
        f:notAfter: {}
        f:notBefore: {}
        f:renewalTime: {}
        f:revision: {}
    manager: controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-09-20T05:14:12Z"
  name: service1-certificate
  namespace: sandbox
  resourceVersion: "5177051"
  selfLink: /apis/cert-manager.io/v1/namespaces/sandbox/certificates/service1-certificate
  uid: 0cf1ea65-92a1-4b03-944e-b847de2c80d9
spec:
  commonName: example.com
  dnsNames:
  - service1
  duration: 24h0m0s
  issuerRef:
    kind: Issuer
    name: ca-issuer
  renewBefore: 12h0m0s
  secretName: service1-certificate
  subject:
    organizations:
    - myorg
  usages:
  - client auth
  - server auth
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-09-20T05:14:13Z"
    message: Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    observedGeneration: 1
    reason: Ready
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  notAfter: "2021-09-21T05:14:13Z"
  notBefore: "2021-09-20T05:14:13Z"
  renewalTime: "2021-09-20T17:14:13Z"
  revision: 5
```

Now as you could see in the configuration I have configured to renew them in 12 hours. However, the secrets created via this custom certificate resource are still aged to two days (the first it was created). I was thinking this tls secret will be renewed via cert manager each day) .i.e.

```
kubectl get secrets service1-certificate service2-certificate -n sandbox -o wide
NAME                        TYPE                DATA   AGE
service1-certificate        kubernetes.io/tls   3      2d23h
service2-certificate        kubernetes.io/tls   3      3d1h
```

Is there is some wrong in my understanding? In the `certmangager` pod logs I do see some error around renewing .i.e.

```
I0920 05:14:04.649158       1 trigger_controller.go:181] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="Certificate must be re-issued" "key”=“sandbox/service1-certificate" "message"="Renewing certificate as renewal was scheduled at 2021-09-19 08:24:13 +0000 UTC" "reason"="Renewing"     
I0920 05:14:04.649235       1 conditions.go:201] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate “service1-certificate" condition "Issuing" to 2021-09-20 05:14:04.649227766 +0000 UTC m=+87949.327215532     
I0920 05:14:04.652174       1 trigger_controller.go:181] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="Certificate must be re-issued" "key"="sandbox/service2 "message"="Renewing certificate as renewal was scheduled at 2021-09-19 10:20:22 +0000 UTC" "reason"="Renewing"     
I0920 05:14:04.652231       1 conditions.go:201] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate “service2-certificate" condition "Issuing" to 2021-09-20 05:14:04.652224302 +0000 UTC m=+87949.330212052     
I0920 05:14:04.671111       1 conditions.go:190] Found status change for Certificate “service2-certificate" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2021-09-20 05:14:04.671094596 +0000 UTC m=+87949.349082328
I0920 05:14:04.671344       1 conditions.go:190] Found status change for Certificate “service1-certificate" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2021-09-20 05:14:04.671332206 +0000 UTC m=+87949.349319948          
I0920 05:14:12.703039       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/controller/certificates-readiness "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key”=“sandbox/service2-certificate" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \”service2-certificate\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"          
I0920 05:14:12.703896       1 conditions.go:190] Found status change for Certificate “service2-certificate" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2021-09-20 05:14:12.7038803 +0000 UTC m=+87957.381868045          
I0920 05:14:12.749502       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/controller/certificates-readiness "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key”=“sandbox/service1-certificate" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \”service1-certificate\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"          
I0920 05:14:12.750096       1 conditions.go:190] Found status change for Certificate “service1-certificate" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2021-09-20 05:14:12.750082572 +0000 UTC m=+87957.428070303     
I0920 05:14:13.009032       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/controller/certificates-key-manager "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key"="sandbox/service1-certificate" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \”service1-certificate\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"     
I0920 05:14:13.117843       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/controller/certificates-readiness "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key”=“sandbox/service2-certificate" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \”service2-certificate\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"     
I0920 05:14:13.119366       1 conditions.go:190] Found status change for Certificate “service2-certificate" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2021-09-20 05:14:13.119351795 +0000 UTC m=+87957.797339520     
I0920 05:14:13.122820       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/controller/certificates-key-manager "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key”=“sandbox\service2-certificate" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \”service-certificate\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"     
I0920 05:14:13.123907       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest “service2-certificate-t92qh" condition "Approved" to 2021-09-20 05:14:13.123896104 +0000 UTC m=+87957.801883833
I0920 05:14:13.248082       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest “service1-certificate-p9stz" condition "Approved" to 2021-09-20 05:14:13.248071551 +0000 UTC m=+87957.926059296
I0920 05:14:13.253488       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest “serivce2-certificate-t92qh" condition "Ready" to 2021-09-20 05:14:13.253474153 +0000 UTC m=+87957.931461871
I0920 05:14:13.388001       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest “service1-certificate-p9stz" condition "Ready" to 2021-09-20 05:14:13.387983783 +0000 UTC m=+87958.065971525
```

Comment: Which issuer do you use? I see there's something related to `HashiCorp`. Also about logs... See [github issue comment](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3501#issuecomment-884003519) so if you need to have more details, they suggest to increase verbosity level, this error is not helpful by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Based on logs and details from certificate you provided it's safe to say **it's working as expected**.

Pay attention to `revision: 5` in your certificate, which means that certificate has been renewed 4 times already. If you try to look there now, this will be 6 or 7 because certificate is updated every 12 hours.

### Logs

First thing which can be really confusing is `error messages` in `cert-manager` pod. This is mostly noisy messages which are not really helpful by itself.

See about it here [Github issue comment](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3501#issuecomment-884003519) and here [github issue 3667](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3667).

In case logs are really needed, `verbosity level` should be increased by setting `args` to `--v=5` in the `cert-manager` deployment. To edit a deployment run following command:

```
kubectl edit deploy cert-manager -n cert-manager
```

### How to check certificate/secret

When certificate is renewed, secret's and certificate's age are not changed, but content is edited, for instance `resourceVersion` in `secret` and `revision` in certificate.

Below are options to check if certificate was renewed:

1. Check this by getting secret in `yaml` before and after renew:

   ```
   kubectl get secret example-certificate -o yaml > secret-before
   ```

And then run `diff` between them. It will be seen that `tls.crt` as well as `resourceVersion` is updated.

2. Look into certificate `revision` and `dates` in status
   (I set duration to minimum possible `1h` and renewBefore `55m`, so it's updated every 5 minutes):

   ```
    $ kubectl get cert example-cert -o yaml
    notAfter: "2021-09-21T14:05:24Z"
    notBefore: "2021-09-21T13:05:24Z"
    renewalTime: "2021-09-21T13:10:24Z"
    revision: 7
   ```
3. Check events in the namespace where certificate/secret are deployed:

   ```
   $ kubectl get events
   117s        Normal   Issuing             certificate/example-cert                The certificate has been successfully issued
   117s        Normal   Reused              certificate/example-cert                Reusing private key stored in existing Secret resource "example-staging-certificate"
   6m57s       Normal   Issuing             certificate/example-cert                Renewing certificate as renewal was scheduled at 2021-09-21 13:00:24 +0000 UTC
   6m57s       Normal   Requested           certificate/example-cert                Created new CertificateRequest resource "example-cert-bs8g6"
   117s        Normal   Issuing             certificate/example-cert                Renewing certificate as renewal was scheduled at 2021-09-21 13:05:24 +0000 UTC
   117s        Normal   Requested           certificate/example-cert                Created new CertificateRequest resource "example-cert-7x8cf" UTC
   ```
4. Look at `certificaterequests`:

   ```
   $ kubectl get certificaterequests
   NAME                 APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER      REQUESTOR                                         AGE
   example-cert-2pxdd   True                True    ca-issuer   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   14m
   example-cert-54zzc   True                True    ca-issuer      system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   4m29s
   example-cert-8vjcm   True                True    ca-issuer      system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   9m29s
   ```
5. Check logs in `cert-manager` pod to see four stages:

   ```
   I0921 12:45:24.000726       1 trigger_controller.go:181] cert-manager/controller/certificates-trigger "msg"="Certificate must be re-issued" "key"="default/example-cert" "message"="Renewing certificate as renewal was scheduled at 2021-09-21 12:45:24 +0000 UTC" "reason"="Renewing"
   I0921 12:45:24.000761       1 conditions.go:201] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "example-cert" condition "Issuing" to 2021-09-21 12:45:24.000756621 +0000 UTC m=+72341.194879378
   I0921 12:45:24.120503       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-cert-mxvbm" condition "Approved" to 2021-09-21 12:45:24.12049391 +0000 UTC m=+72341.314616684
   I0921 12:45:24.154092       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "example-cert-mxvbm" condition "Ready" to 2021-09-21 12:45:24.154081971 +0000 UTC m=+72341.348204734
   ```

### Note

Very important that not all `issuers` support `duration` and `renewBefore` flags. E.g. `letsencrypt` still doesn't work with it and have 90 default days.

[Refence](https://cert-manager.io/docs/release-notes/release-notes-1.1/#duration).